# Why my MATLink must execute the command `OpenMATLAB[]` twice to realize once normal `OpenMATLAB[]` command?

Tags: packages, interoperability, matlab, matlink

## Problem description

To use Matlab code in Mathematica I have tried to use the package MATLink. However, everytime I run the code below

```mathematica
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]
```

I will have the error information

```
MATLink has lost connection to the MATLAB engine; please restart MATLink to create a new connection. 
If this was a crash, then please try to reproduce it and open a new issue, 
making sure to provide all the details necessary to reproduce it.
```

However, when I run the command `OpenMATLAB[]` again, everything goes well and I can use the Matlab command within Mathematica now. But every time I want to execute `OpenMATLAB[]` to establish a connection with Matlab, the error happens and I have to execute the command again. What can I do?

## Version information

- Matlab: `23.2.0.2391609 (R2023b) Update 2`
- Mathematica: `"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`
- Windows 10